# Coding Buttons in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

This has to be completed in visual studio. I'm new to visual studio and I'm having trouble. How do I code the buttons so that one doubles the integer and the other takes half of the integer?

Has a text box, with a label next to it saying "Enter an integer:"

Has two buttons, one saying "DOUBLE" and one saying "HALF".

Pressing the DOUBLE button, should generate a Message box (MsgBox) that displays two times the number in the text box, and clears the text box.

Pressing the HALF button, should generate a Message box (MsgBox) that displays half the number in the text box, and clears the text box.

Comment: This question is **way too broad** for this format.  Please narrow down what you have tried and what isn't working.  Also, Visual Studio is a Development Environment for ***MULTIPLE*** Languages, you'll need to specify which Language you are working with.

Answer (score -1):

To add code for buttons :

1. Double click on the button (in the designer). this will create the button handler function so you can write your code
2. Get the text from the textbox and assign it to a string variable
3. Convert this variable to an integer
4. Show the message box with the new value (either doubled or halfed)